# how to change the inapproapriate value of the row with a mean value or with nun or 0 in dataframe pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, data-cleaning

i tried to do a some cleaning in my dataframe with python. This column 'Militarydeaths from all causes' has a object type but it must be a int or float type . But in this column there are some list values, for example 'Included with Germany'. I want to replace these values with 0, nun or mean values to change the data type this column

this is the example of 'Militarydeaths from all causes' column

```
| Counry | Militarydeaths from all causes |
| ------ | -------------------------------|
| USA    | 12000                          |
| Germany| Included with Germany          |
```

Comment: You can use `pd.to_numeric(df[that_column_name], errors='coerce')` but you may need to do some additional cleaning if the "numeric" values aren't in a standard format (e.g., some have commas)

Comment: The code @ALollz provided will replace all values that can not be converted to number with 0. 
After that you can use 
`df['Militarydeaths from all causes'].fillna(value = 0, method = [your_method] inplace=True)` to replace with mean/mode/median etc.